# how to fix the path problem while saving neural network

Tags: python-3.x

I want to save the model in pythorch. but colaboratory (colab.research.google.com) ask me to invalid syntax of PATH.

> File "", line 7
> }, "abc.corpus")
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

how did i remove it.

I want to make a urdu pos tagger as a project. I use LSTM with CRF and got 91% Accuracy.
I use a code from there but this gives me a path error

```
torch.save({
            'epoch': epoch,
            'model_state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'loss': loss,
            ...
            }, "new.corpus")
```

and

```
torch.save(the_model.state_dict(), "new.corpus")
```

I expect that there must the model save in file, but there is path error of file

Answer (score 0):

- There is a syntax error that is the first parameter of save, it is an object so there must be curly braces.
- there the file type of path (not corpus) is .pt or .pth

  torch.save({the_model.state_dict()}, "new.pt")